# Bot confirmation after user reacts not displaying in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want the user to answer a "yes or no" question using reactions. However, there is a bug in which when the tagged user reacts to the question, the bot is not sending a message on whether or not the tagged user wants to negotiate. Here is my code below.

```
     const yesEmoji = '✅';
        const noEmoji = '❌';
        client.on('message', (negotiate) => {
            const listen = negotiate.content; 
            const userID = negotiate.author.id;
            var prefix = '!';
            var negotiating = false; 
            let mention = negotiate.mentions.users.first();
        
            if(listen.toUpperCase().startsWith(prefix + 'negotiate with '.toUpperCase()) && (mention)) {
                negotiate.channel.send(`<@${mention.id}>, do you want to negotiate with ` + `<@${userID}>`)
                .then(async (m) => {
                    await m.react(yesEmoji);
                    await m.react(noEmoji);

                    //get an answer from the mentioned user
                    const filter = (reaction, user) => user.id === mention.id;
                    const collector = negotiate.createReactionCollector(filter);
                    collector.on('collect', (reaction) => {
                         if (reaction.emoji.name === yesEmoji) {
                              negotiate.channel.send('The mentioned user is okay to negotiate with you!');
                             
                         } 
                         else {
                              negotiate.channel.send('The mentioned user is not okay to negotiate with you...')
                         }
                    })
                })
                negotiating = true;
            }
        })

So far, the code displays the reaction but it does not make the bot send a message whether the tagged user is ok or not ok to negotiate with the user that tagged them.
```

UPDATE:
I managed to get the bot to send a message whether the tagged user is ok or not ok to negotiate with the user that tagged them. Now there is an error in which is shown after 10 seconds (specified time). Here is the updated code below:

```
const yesEmoji = '✅';
const noEmoji = '❌';

client.on("message", async negotiate => {
    const listen = negotiate.content; 
    let mention = negotiate.mentions.users.first();
    if(listen.toUpperCase().startsWith(prefix + 'negotiate with '.toUpperCase()) && (mention)) {
        let mention = negotiate.mentions.users.first();
        let msg = await negotiate.channel.send(`${mention} do you want to negotiate with ${negotiate.author}`);
        var negotiating = false;

        await msg.react(yesEmoji);
        await msg.react(noEmoji);

        const filter = (reaction, member) => {
        return reaction.emoji.name === yesEmoji || reaction.emoji.name === noEmoji && member.id === mention.id;
        };

        msg.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time'] })
        .then(collected => {
            const reaction = collected.first();
            if (reaction.emoji.name === yesEmoji) {
            negotiating = true;
            negotiate.reply('The mentioned user agreed to negotiate with you!');
            }
            else return negotiate.reply('The mentioned user did not agree to negotiate with you.')
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a much easier solution to your problem:

```js
    const yesEmoji = '✅';
    const noEmoji = '❌';

    let mention = negotiate.mentions.users.first();
    if(mention.id === negotiate.author.id) return message.channel.send("You cannot tag yourself!");
    let msg = await negotiate.channel.send(`${mention} do you want to negotiate with ${negotiate.author}`);
    var negotiating = false;

    await msg.react(yesEmoji);
    await msg.react(noEmoji);

    const filter = (reaction, member) => {
      return (member.id === mention.id && reaction.emoji.name === yesEmoji) || (member.id === mention.id && reaction.emoji.name === noEmoji);
    };

    msg.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time'] })
      .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();
        if (reaction.emoji.name === yesEmoji) {
          negotiating = true;
          negotiate.channel.send('The mentioned user is okay to negotiate with you!');
        }
        else if (reaction.emoji.name === noEmoji) return negotiate.channel.send('The mentioned user is not okay to negotiate with you...')
      }).catch(err => {
        if(err) return message.channel.send(`${mention} did not react within the 10 seconds!`);
      })
```

So first we got the two emojis, we want the user to react with. `mention` is our mentioned user, `msg` is the "yes or no" question and `negotiating` is set to false by default. At first we react to the question with our emojis. In this example I am using `awaitReactions`, because it is very simple to use. For this we need a filter. In this case I named the variable also `filter`. `filter` checks if the reaction wether is `yesEmoji` or `noEmoji` and if the user who reacted is `mention` (our mentioned user). Then in `awaitReactions` we want only **1** reaction (yes or no), and I set the time to 10 seconds, but you can change it if you want. After `awaitReactions` is set up we want to collect our reaction. This is done in `.then()`. `collected` gives us the reactions, and we only want the first one, so we store `collected.first()` in `reaction`. Now we have a really simple if-else statement. If the reacted emoji is `yesEmoji`, `negotiating` will be set to true and a message gets sent into the channel, otherwise it will only sent a message and return.

It is important to set `negotiating` only to `true` if the user reacted with `yesEmoji`. In your code it is `true` even if nothing happens, because as you run the command everything in that command code will be executed. and your last line there was `negotiating = true;`. And I think that is not what you wanted to do.

Comment: There is an error. 
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: just use `client.on("message", async negotiate => {...})` @PranavSivakumar

Comment: Another error takes place:   
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "#<Collection>".]

Comment: please show me your updated code, as it works without problems for me @PranavSivakumar

Comment: Yes, I updated my coded. The error takes place after the specified amount of time.

Comment: I edited my answer. Now it should work without problems. Btw it worked before, the user you mentioned just didn't react within the 10 seconds. With `.catch` we say if there is an error (we said that the error is "time" in our `awaitReactions`) it just sends a message that the user did not react within the 10 seconds. @PranavSivakumar

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was wondering if there was a way to prevent the user from tagging themselves. Also, there is a yes message displaying when the author reacts yes.

Comment: No problem! I've edited my answer again. Now you cannot tag yourself!

Comment: Also, there is another problem occurring. The yes message is showing when the author reacts to yes. The yes or no messages should only display when the tagged user reacts.

Comment: Edited my answer. Sorry this was my bad, it was a logical error by me in the filter. But now it should be fixed. @PranavSivakumar